# Banshee wont Start after Installing Last.fm Fingerprint Extension

Tags: banshee

Banshee was working on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS machine. I installed the Last.fm Finger Print Extension, and then Banshee would no longer start. The mouse icon changes to busy for a few seconds, and then it returns to normal and nothing else happens. I have tried uninstalling the extension, uninstalling and reinstalling Banshee, and deleting `~/.config/banshee-1`.

`apt list --installed` reports:

```
banshee/xenial,now 2.9.0+really2.6.2-7ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]
```